# TYPO3: Own content element dataProcessing gives back an array

Tags: typo3, css-tables, fluid

The problem is the following. I have create an accordion as content element which has three tables.

1. The first one is the **tt_content** table which has a 1-1 relation to **accordionsettings** table.
2. The **accordionsettings** table then has a 1-n relation to the **accordioncontent**.
3. **accordioncontent**

This is the result on my backend:

[image]

So far so good everything works fine. The problem appears when I am trying to render multiple elements on the same page. What I mean by that:

**CASE**: I have an accordion content element on the top of the Website and one at the bottom. That means, I've created two different content elements.

I have my data proccesing on my

**ext_name/Configuration/Setup/tt_content.typoscript**

```
ext_accordion < lib.contentElement
ext_accordion {
    templateRootPaths.30 = {$ExtPrivate}Templates/
    partialRootPaths.30 = {$ExtPrivate}Partials/
    templateName = Accordion.html
    dataProcessing {
        30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        30 {
            table = accordionsettings

            as = accordionsettings
            dataProcessing {
                50 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
                50 {
                    if.isTrue.field = accordion_content_relation

                    table = accordioncontent

                    pidInList = this
                    where.field = uid
                    where.intval = 1
                    where.dataWrap = accordionsettings = |

                    as = accordionContents
                    dataProcessing {
                        70 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                        70 {
                            references.fieldName = files
                            as = images
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get in the Frontend when I am debugging it is the following:

[image]

**The problem:** I would like to render both on the website, but as if you can see, it gave me back the results as an array. That means that if I want to declare a variable on fluid to read the information, I will have to include the number 0 and 1. If I had three accordion elements then I would had to include 2, too. This is not dynamic and not an option. The variables at the moment are the following:

1. **accordionsettings.0.data.accordion_speed**
2. **accordionsettings.0.accordionContents**

**Question:** How can I get the variables like this and still have both accordions rendered?

1. **accordionsettings.data.accordion_speed**
2. **accordionsettings.accordionContents**

Do I have to rebuild the whole thing in a different way? I am in dead end right now.

**EDIT** for @Claus Due

I tried to create a loop and it looked like that:

```
<f:for each="{accordionsettings}" as="settings" key="key">
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x">
        <div class="cell">
            <f:alias map="{
                speed: settings.data.accordion_speed,
                multiexpand:settings.data.accordion_multiexpand,
                allClosed:settings.data.accordion_all_closed,
                disabled:settings.data.accordion_disabled,
                accordionContents:settings.accordionContents
                }">
                <f:debug>{settings}</f:debug>
                    <f:render partial="Accordion/Accordion" arguments="{speed: speed, multiexpand: multiexpand, allClosed: allClosed, disabled: disabled, accordionContents: accordionContents}"/>
            </f:alias>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</f:for>
```

But what I get in frontend is the following:

[image]

It renders all the accordion elements for each element created.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the `FilesProcessor` will always give you file**s**, hence the naming. So in Fluid you would indeed have to either access with a `.0` to reach the properties, or pass the individual arrays to a section or partial that can then use just the property names in each array.

But that doesn't change this simple fact: if you need to render all of those but not have to reference them manually then you need to create a loop.

The other problem is that you do create IRRE which is by definition an array of records and will naturally become an array of template variables. If you only have a single settings object, always, then I suggest *not* creating that as IRRE but rather put the relation to your accordions directly in a column. That gives you an array of accordion panels which each can have an array of files (so in other words, they're still arrays but with a cleaner structure).

Comment: I ve edited my question. I tried the loop thing before and this is the result

Comment: The more precise question text helped. `where.intval = 1` would cause an SQL query that selects all records with `accordionsettings = 1` and that's probably not correct. In any case you should take a look at the rather complex IRRE structure you have built, and clean that up a little. That also makes the SQL queries easier to create ;)

Comment: `<f:for each="{accordionsettings}" as="settings" key="key">` is also a bit of an issue since this will overwrite the `{settings}` variable that is automatically transferred between templates. Unless you really, really, *really* know what you're doing you should avoid writing to this variable in Fluid - and only ever declare/change it in TS, controller, etc.

Comment: the "settings" variable was an example. i changed the name to "settingsAcc" but i still get the same results. Do you think that i do something like that would be better? https://prnt.sc/knbnmh

Comment: Going from your diagram, if you related your `Accordion` with IRRE to the tt_content then yes - that should help with all the features that must use these relations, e.g. your TS query settings.

Comment: `<f:render partial="Accordion/Accordion" arguments="{settingsAcc}` />` inside your loop should then pass the data as the variables you need, without having to use `f:alias` at all. This also would reduce the sources of possible confusion, passing the entire array of a record instead of mapping individual variables where you can make typos, wrong references, forget a variable and so on, and would have to change this passing of variables every time you add something.

Answer (score 0):

Since the accordion settings belong to the accordion and not to its items, you should move them to a field of the parent record rather than each of its child records.

So IMHO the accordionsettings table should not be the connecting intermediate table between accordion and items, but just another table that is connected to the accordion table just as the items table. Instead there should be an additional panels table to group more than just single items and some additional data like i.e. panel title.

So it would be

```
accordion => 1:n panels
accordion => 1:1 settings
panels => 1:n items
```

Instead of providing the settings with an own table you could go for a flexform to provide them, since this currently is the default way of providing settings for any kind of plugin.

Comment: How is this going to help me to separate each accordion? If i use the way you just explained to me, if i debug it, what will be the result while i have two different accordions? Do not forget i am not using the elements as plugins but as content elements. That means the tt_content comes in to the game. About the tables: Do you mean something like that? http://prntscr.com/knbnmh . Please keep in mind i am relative new to this.

Comment: Flexforms are not necessarily connected to plugins but can be stored with "real" CTypes too. So for each accordion parent container, you would get an own set of flexform data providing the configuration for that particular container. The structure used for both of them would be the same, but the values could be different. So this would be the separation you are asking for. Since the configuration belongs to the accordion and not the panel, this would be a cleaner approach than putting the configuration into the panels.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I did not had to change anything on my database structure **ALTHOUGH** i agree with both @Jo Haenau and @Claus Due that i did not use the most efficient way to build my database but:

On my dataProcessing i had to include:

```
ext_accordion < lib.contentElement
ext_accordion {
    templateRootPaths.30 = {$ExtPrivate}Templates/
    partialRootPaths.30 = {$ExtPrivate}Partials/
    templateName = Accordion.html
    dataProcessing {
        30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        30 {
            table = accordionsettings

            pidInList = this
            where = uid=
            where.dataWrap = |{field:accordion_settings_relation}

            as = accordionsettings
            dataProcessing {
              50 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
              50 {
                if.isTrue.field = accordion_content_relation

                table = accordioncontent

                pidInList = this
                where.field = uid
                where.intval = 1
                where.dataWrap = accordionsettings = |

                as = accordionContents
                dataProcessing {
                    70 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                    70 {
                        references.fieldName = files
                        as = images
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So what i did is to first select the pid where the content is saved:

**pidInList = this**

then select the UID of the tt_content element according to its' foreign table.

**where = uid=**

**where.dataWrap = |{field:accordion_settings_relation}**

And the result is the following:

[image]

Now i can use the variables with the 0.

Not the clearest way, but it works perfectly